# Jquery sum and subtract based values on textbox

Tags: jquery

1) I have **3 text boxes** if first text box is filled second is automatically updated from DB and added to fill third.

2) however if 3rd text box is chosen then second is automatically updated from DB,  subtract 3rd and second to fill 1st text box.

```
    <td>Sending Amount</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" id = "sending"/></td>


    <td>Charge</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" id = "charge"/></td>


    <td>Total Amount</td>
    <td><input class="txt" type="text" name="txt" id = "totalAmount"/></td>
</tr>
```

```
    $(function () {
        var sending = $('input:text[id$=sending]').keyup(foo);
        var charge = $('input:text[id$=charge]').keyup(foo);            
        var totalAmount = $('input:text[id$=totalAmount]').keyup(foo);   

     function foo() {

            var value1 = sending.val();
            var value2 = charge.val();               
            var sum = add(value1, value2);
            $('input:text[id$=totalAmount]').val(sum);
    var sub = sub(value1, value2);
            $('input:text[id$=sending]').val(sub);
        }

        function add() {

            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++) {
                if (IsNumeric(arguments[i])) {
                    sum += parseFloat(arguments[i]);
                }
            }
            return sum;
        }

  function sub() 
         {
            var sub= 0;
            ***//need to create subtract function***
            }
            return sub;
        }

        function IsNumeric(input) {
            return (input - 0) == input && input.length > 0;
        }
    });
</script>
```

**addition is working fine subtraction is not displaying correct value.**

Tried below script, I think it does add and subtract .

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
    var sending = $('input:text[id$=sending]').keyup(foo);
    var charge = $('input:text[id$=charge]').keyup(foo);            
    var totalAmount = $('input:text[id$=totalAmount]').keyup(foo);   
 function foo() {
        var value1 = sending.val();
        var value2 = charge.val();   

        if(IsNumeric(value2)){
        if(IsNumeric(value1)){
        var value3 = parseFloat(value1) + parseFloat(value2);
        $('input:text[id$=totalAmount]').val(value3);
        }}

        value3 = totalAmount.val();
        if(IsNumeric(value3)){
        if(IsNumeric(value2)){
        value1 = parseFloat(value3) - parseFloat(value2);
        $('input:text[id$=sending]').val(value1);
        }}
    }
    function IsNumeric(input) {
        return (input - 0) == input && input.length > 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are ever going to be two parameters why do you need a function `add()`, why not just do `sum = value1 + value2`

Similarly, `sub = value1 - value2` should do the trick.

If you *have* to use `sub` function, you can prolly do something like

```
function sub(value1,value2) 
     {
        var sub= value1 - value2;
        return sub;
     }
```

Comment: tried to do with out add() and sub() its not displaying correct sum and sub values.